# Removing user accounts

Tags: command-line, user-management

I'm new in Linux. I've created 5 users using `adduser`
and then removed 'em with `deluser` according to *man* pages. 
On GUI's User Accounts I don't see them.All gone,but in Terminal `cd /home/.../`  I still can see all users and even navigate and touch file in those accounts folders.`id user` also gives: *no such user*. What command(s) shell I use to remove them from bash?
Your help will be very appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you have deleted the user accounts, neither `deluser` nor `userdel` will know anything about them or their home directories, since the corresponding `/etc/passwd` entries are gone. Just manually delete the directories once you have backed up any valuable data:

```
sudo rm -r /home/user1 /home/user2 ...
```

You could, of course, have deleted the directories while deleting the user like the other answers suggested.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo deluser --remove-home your_user` deletes the home directories as well as the user entries.

The additional option `--remove-all-files` even removes all the files owned by the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
userdel -r user_id
```

where `-r` removes the user's home_dir when being deleted

Comment: The manual page of `userdel(8)` says: "`userdel` is a low level utility for removing users. On Debian, administrators should usually use `deluser(8)` instead." So -1.